# Elastic Beanstalk - SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a simple javascript site that I am hosting on Elastic Beanstalk. Part of this app uses an SQLite database to handle logging and analytics.

Whenever a new version of the site is deployed to the Elastic Beanstalk instance it  destroys the previous version and in turn I lose the contents of my SQLite database.

Does anybody have any solutions to this issue? Would storing the SQLite database in an S3 bucket work?

I know I can use an RDS database but I am trying to avoid rewriting my code.

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, backing up to S3 makes sense. You can use [platform hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platform-hooks.html) to do this almost elegantly. Create an `.ebextensions` directory in the root of your app, and in it, make a file called `sqlite_backup.conf`:

```
files:
  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/preinit/01_sqlite_backup.sh:
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/bin/sh
      # insert shell script which backs up sqlite to s3, something like the following:
      # set backup directory variables
      SRCDIR='/tmp/s3backups'
      DESTDIR='path/to/s3folder'
      BUCKET='s3bucket'
      NOWDATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
      sqlite3 test.db ‘.dump’ > $SRCDIR/dbbackup
      cd $SRCDIR
      tar -czPf $NOWDATE-backup.tar.gz dbbackup
      # upload backup to s3
      /usr/bin/s3cmd put $SRCDIR/$NOWDATE-backup.tar.gz s3://$BUCKET/$DESTDIR/
      # check if these persist across deploys - they shouldn't, but if they do, you don't have to backup to S3 (you also have to worry about filling up the disk).
```

And another called `sqlite_restore.conf`:

```
files:
  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/postinit/99_sqlite_restore.sh:
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/bin/sh
      # insert shell script which restores sqlite from s3
```

Due to their placement in `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/(pre|post)init` they will be run at the right time. The files are executed in alphabetic order by filename, hence the names I picked.

Good shell scripts for backing up DBs to S3: https://github.com/lumerit/s3-shell-backups